# parsing a loop generated $_post in php?

Tags: php, parsing, post, loops

I am sending the results of a loop by post to a php file for processing (insertion into db). But I'm not sure how to get the results out in the most efficient way.
right now it's either 
1. updating $_POST['name-id'] and $_POST['occupation-id]
or
2. creating $_POST['new_name-#'] and $_POST['new_occupation-#] with a variable # starting at 1 and counting up.

I am stuck on an efficient way of pulling all that data out and transferring it to variables + how to separate the names from the new names

in php document one there is basically a 2 column table in a form that is method post and on submit goes to the other php file. code is a bit convoluted so wanted to hold off on putting it all up"

```
while ( $tracks = mysql_fetch_array($trackstring) ){
    echo "<li class=\"tracklist\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"tracknum-".$tracks['song_id']."\" id=\"tracknum-".$tracks['song_id']."\" value=\"".$tracks['song_tracknumber']."\"/>
    <input type=\"text\" name=\"trackname-".$tracks['song_id']."\" id=\"trackname-".$tracks['song_id']."\" value=\"".$tracks['song_title']."\"/></li>";
    }

for ($i = 0; $i < ( (mysql_num_rows($trackstring) < 1) ? 20 : 5 ); $i++){
//for($i=1; $i< $numtracks; $i++){
    $count++;
        echo "<li class=\"tracklist\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"newtracknum-".$count."\" id=\"newtracknum-".$count."\" value=\"\"/><input type=\"text\" name=\"newtrackname-".$count."\" id=\"newtrackname=".$count."\" value=\"\"/></li>";
        }
```

and I need to pull that out in the other php file and sort it so that I can take the trackname-# and tracknumber-# in the value to update the id# of the db.  I feel like I might be able to get it working by passing some invisible things into the array

Comment: I didn't down-vote this question - in fact I removed the down-vote, but the question seems unclear. Could you provide more detail?

Comment: What does the `$_POST` global have to do with *sending* data by POST? `$_POST` is for incoming POST data and you generally don't alter it. Please provide an example.

Comment: i guess i can't quite get my own head around it and that's keeping me from being clear. i tried editing the initial comment though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is each loop iteration doing a seperate post (e.g. a fresh curl_exec() or whatever?) In that case, each request will be independent of all the others and you could just re-use the same field names for each one.

If it's all within a request, then use a sort-of-feature of PHP and force it to create an array from the post data. If you append `[]` to the end of a field name, PHP will treat that field as an array and save the data as such while it's processing the post.

e.g.:

```
<input type="text" name="arr[]" value="hi" />
<input type="text" name="arr[]" value="there" />
```

when processed by PHP will result in:

```
$_POST = array(
   'arr' => array(
        0 => 'hi',
        1 => 'there'
   )
)
```

You can even force subscripts if you so choose, just put them inside the `[]`, e.g. `name="arr[12]"` and `name="arr[42]"` will give you

```
$_POST = array(
   'arr' => array(
        12 => 'hi',
        42 => 'there'
   )
)
```